# ParseJson not valid When message is received from topic auto complete in logic app

Tags: azure

I am new in the logic app. I want develop one new logic app when message received from topic content data couldn't parse as json , its throwing error like **"

InvalidJSON. The 'content' property of actions of type 'ParseJson' must be valid JSON. The provided value cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

."**
after decode my string my json like below

*{"Id":"ddd9cc1e-8e41-4684-be2e-cd874398e209","Type":"userData","Content":[{"EmpId":1,"EmpName":"Raja1"},{"EmpId":2,"EmpName":"Raja2"}]}*

Any one suggest whats wrong am doing here? Attached some screenshot for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtK5i.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bTHG.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to convert an xml to json. You are very close - only issue is @json() expects either

1. A **`string`** that is a valid JSON object.
2. An **`application/xml`** object to convert to JSON.

The @base64toString() is converting to a string, but you really need to let @json() know this is #2 and not #1, so changing expression to this should work:

```
@{json(xml(base64toBinary(triggerBody()[contentdata])))[foo]}
```